# SQL Access: how to obtain output involving multiple tables without running 2 queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access, multiple-tables

I would like to find out the most popular genre of film for a certain age group, for example 20-30 year-olds. I'm quite new to SQL and would appreciate any help I can get, apologies if this is too minor.

The relevant tables for this query are:

```
FILM {FID (PK), ..., Film_Title}
MEMBER {MID (PK), ..., Date_of_Birth}
LIST {MID (FK), FID (FK)}
GENRE {GID (PK), Genre}
FILM_ACTOR_DIRECTOR_GENRE {FID (FK), ..., GID (FK)}
```

FILM and MEMBER table should be quite self-explanatory, while a LIST is a selection of films a MEMBER wishes to rent. It's like a shopping basket. Each member only has one list and each list can contain many films. FILM_ACTOR_DIRECTOR_GENRE contains Genre belonging to each film. Each film can only have one genre.

So far I have managed to get an output which shows:

```
Genre     # People Aged 20-30
-------   -------------------
Action             5
Comedy             4
Horror             2
etc.              etc.
```

However it involves creating a table and then running another query. Is there a way to obtain the most popular genre within a particular age group without having to run 2 separate queries?

The 2 queries I've used are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Genre.Genre_Name, Member.Date_of_Birth
INTO Genre_by_Age
FROM
((((Genre 
INNER JOIN Film_Actor_Director_Genre ON Genre.GID = Film_Actor_Director_Genre.GID)
INNER JOIN Film ON Film_Actor_Director_Genre.FID = Film.FID) 
INNER JOIN List ON Film.FID = List.FID)
INNER JOIN Member ON Member.MID = List.MID)
WHERE (((Member.[Date_of_Birth]) Between #4/16/1995# And #4/16/1985#));
```

for creating the new table with information I want, and:

```
SELECT Genre_Name, COUNT(*) as Number_of_People_aged_20_to_30
FROM Genre_by_Age
GROUP BY Genre_Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

to obtain the output shown above.

Is there a way to obtain the above result without running 2 separate queries? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a subquery?

```
SELECT Genre_Name, COUNT(*) as Number_of_People_aged_20_to_30
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Genre.Genre_Name, Member.Date_of_Birth
      FROM ((((Genre 
      INNER JOIN Film_Actor_Director_Genre ON Genre.GID = Film_Actor_Director_Genre.GID)
      INNER JOIN Film ON Film_Actor_Director_Genre.FID = Film.FID) 
      INNER JOIN List ON Film.FID = List.FID)
      INNER JOIN Member ON Member.MID = List.MID)
      WHERE (((Member.[Date_of_Birth]) Between #4/16/1995# And #4/16/1985#))
     ) as t
GROUP BY Genre_Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to reactivate this thread so i'm just posting a comment here..please let me know if I should have done something else instead. 

Anyway, I would like to limit the results now to only show the top 5 genres rather than all the genres. Is it possible to do that? I tried using `SELECT TOP 5` but it actually limits the list of people and the films they have chosen, so I end up getting Action — 5 as a result as opposed to Action — 19, Comedy — 10, etc

Comment: A new question should be asked as a new question, rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT Genre.Genre_Name, count(Member.MID) as Number_of_People_aged_20_to_30
FROM
((((Genre 
INNER JOIN Film_Actor_Director_Genre ON Genre.GID = Film_Actor_Director_Genre.GID)
INNER JOIN Film ON Film_Actor_Director_Genre.FID = Film.FID) 
INNER JOIN List ON Film.FID = List.FID)
INNER JOIN Member ON Member.MID = List.MID)
WHERE (((Member.[Date_of_Birth]) Between #4/16/1995# And #4/16/1985#))
GROUP BY Genre.Genre_Name
ORDER BY count(Member.MID) DESC;
```

Comment: I ran this query and an error came up: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'count(DISTINCT Member.MID)'" — not sure what could be wrong? code seems right to me...

Comment: Ok, apparently COUNT(DISTINCT) doesn't work with Access.

`SELECT Genre.Genre_Name, count(Member.MID) as Number_of_People_aged_20_to_30 FROM 
(Select DISTINCT Member.MID
FROM ((((Genre INNER JOIN Film_Actor_Director_Genre ON Genre.GID = Film_Actor_Director_Genre.GID) INNER JOIN Film ON Film_Actor_Director_Genre.FID = Film.FID) INNER JOIN List ON Film.FID = List.FID) INNER JOIN Member ON Member.MID = List.MID) WHERE (((Member.[Date_of_Birth]) Between #4/16/1995# And #4/16/1985#)) 
GROUP BY Genre.Genre_Name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC);`

but error: ORDER BY clause (COUNT(*))conflicts with DISTINCT

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to reactivate this thread so i'm just posting a comment here..please let me know if I should have done something else instead. 

Anyway, I would like to limit the results now to only show the top 5 genres rather than all the genres. Is it possible to do that? I tried using SELECT TOP 5 but it actually limits the list of people and the films they have chosen, so I end up getting Action — 5 as a result as opposed to Action — 19, Comedy — 10, etc